# grails Resource Plugin works on local but not on server

Tags: grails

I am using **grails resource plugin** in my project. All my static application are stored there and retrieved. However, it works when i run on local but when i do same on server the static contents are retrieved from server only instead of cache. I'm using ***Tomcat server***. any help?

Comment: Give us your grails version and your BuildConfig.groovy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install cached resourses plugin: http://grails.org/plugin/cached-resources